# Problems importing less stylesheets in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I will give as detailed of an explanation as possible...

The directory where the stylesheets are located looks like this:

[image]

As is required with the newest version of Meteor, I renamed each file in the sub folders with the `.import.less` extension.

[image]

To import the less files, I added the `@import` designations to the files at root of the folder. For example, bootstrap.less looks like this:

[image]

However, the stylesheets are not importing correctly to client, so I must have done something wrong here. Not sure what it is, as I've tried everything I can think of. If someone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure the path in your import statements is correct? Is it supposed to be relative to the path of `bootstrap.less` or the application itself in which case it would be `client/stylesheets/less/bootstrap`

Comment: @MichelFloyd I tried doing that via `/client/stylesheets/less/bootstrap` but it still doesn't import the less properly because I cannot see any changes in the template after making said changes.

Comment: What do you see in your inspector in terms of 404s on resources? It should show you the paths it was trying to load.